# Sass Variables are not changing the css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to follow the michael hartl tutorial and I'm trying to implement variables in the css using sass to change the name of the colors from #999 to $black

So this is a example code that I extracted from a bootstrap custom.css.scss

```
$black: #999;
```

I save, I close, I change and what I get is

```
h2 {
   color: #999;
}
```

Is this supposed to work like this? Do I have to change everything by hand? The purpose isn't to automatically change everything?

EDIT 1:What I thinked that would do:

```
$black: #999;

h2{
   color: black
}
```

Basicly automaticly change from HEX code to the variable name.

Comment: That's how variables work...you set `$black` and then you use that colour where you want it...What's your issue?

Comment: So when I set my variable I can use the hex code and the name of the color? What I thinked that would do was change all the code.

Answer (score 0):

CSS (currently) doesn't support variables like this, so when the scss is compiled into css it does substitiion

So if your scss file is like this

```
$black: #999
h2 {
    color: $black;
}
```

The css output will be

```
h2 {
    color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$black: #999;

h2{
   color: $black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking but...

If you define a variable such as

```
$black: #999
```

you can use it **wherever** you want that `color` applied.

So if you define

```
h2 {    
   color:$black;    
}
```

in your SCSS file it will output

```
h2 {
    color:#999;
}
```

in your **generated** CSS file.

If you decide to change the color later you can just change `$black` in your SCSS file and it will iterate through to the **newly generated** css file.

With SCSS, you should **never** need to edit the CSS file.

Oh, one final thing...you really shouldn't use actual color names for variables. You should use something more generic like `$my_dark_color` because there will come a time when $black` may end up being a really dark blue or something.